# Unable to convert AnyPublisher to Another AnyPublisher

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to fetch some model from an AnyPublisher and using model get an array from another publisher. Following is my code:

```
public func getAllMyAppointments() -> AnyPublisher<[TelehealthMyAppointmentsListEntity]?, Error> {
    telehealthMyAppointmentsAPIAccessTokenUseCase.getAccessToken().map { tokenDetails in
        provider.getAllMyAppointments(with: tokenDetails)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I am getting following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher<[TelehealthMyAppointmentsListEntity]?, any Error>' to closure result type '[TelehealthMyAppointmentsListEntity]?'

Following is signature for my methods:

```
func getAccessToken() -> (AnyPublisher<MyAppointmentsAPIAccessTokenDetails, Error>)
func getAllMyAppointments(with accessInformation: MyAppointmentsAPIAccessTokenDetails) -> AnyPublisher<[TelehealthMyAppointmentsListEntity]?, Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `map` when you mean `flatMap`.

For an `AnyPublisher<T>`, the point of `map` is to use a `(T) -> U` to convert `AnyPublisher<T>` to `AnyPublisher<U>`.

But what you want is to use a `(T) -> AnyPublisher<U>` to do the same thing. That is precisely `flatMap`:

```
public func getAllMyAppointments() -> AnyPublisher<[TelehealthMyAppointmentsListEntity]?, Error> {
    telehealthMyAppointmentsAPIAccessTokenUseCase.getAccessToken().flatMap { tokenDetails in
        provider.getAllMyAppointments(with: tokenDetails)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```